# struts2 token concept Could not find token name in params

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am new to struts2 by googling some sites I found the token concept to stop double submit concept.
every time I am getting the `invalid.token` page. I followed stackoverflow's suggestions but getting same error.
I am using struts2.1.8 is this is the problem. please suggest me.

my struts.xml (sample)

```
<action name="managexy" class="com.start.view.xyaction" method="createxy">
    <interceptor-ref name="token" ></interceptor-ref> 
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">x.y.page</result>
    <result name="error" type="tiles">x.y.page</result>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">x.y.page</result>
    <result name="invalid.token">invalid_token.jsp</result>
</action>
```

my **jsp page**

```
<s:actionerror/><s:actionmessage/>
<s:form action="manageAgent" method="post" validate="true">

    <s:token name="token"/>  

    ...some fields..
    <tr>
        <td><s:submit theme="simple" cssClass="button" value="Submit"/></td>
        <td><s:reset theme="simple" cssClass="button" value="clear"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Remove `name="token"` from token tag.

Comment: @Aleksandr I tried with out name="token" also but getting same thing

Comment: Examine submitted values. Do you see token parameter there?

Comment: no parameter visible here, directly token page is visible.

Comment: OT: `<shtml:` seems overkill to me. Isn't `<s:` enough ?

Comment: @Andrea Ligios
I used like this
<%@ taglib prefix="shtml" uri="/struts-tags"%>
so <shtml: is not a problem

Comment: You need to open some dev tool and look for network tab to see posted values.

Comment: @Aleksandr I observed that in firebug with persist mode

Comment: So there are other values but no token parameters? Also if you rendered html for your form is there hidden fields for token?

Comment: @Ramben I know you used that and I know it's not a problem. It just seems overkill to me, meaning it seems too verbose, and "unstandard" because 99.9% of the other developers use just <s: and <shtml: makes also the code less readable

Comment: This problem may be because of result type you are using i.e "tiles". Check it out by removing tiles result type & redirecting to simple jsp page.

Comment: @PravinVarpe: Makes no sense.